# check if item is in list and then return the item

Tags: python

I have a structure like this:

```
['a;1,2,3\n', 'b;abc\n', ...]
```

in other words: it is a `List` with items like this: `'id;element1,element2,...\n'`

now I want to check if the List contains a element with the id = `"b"` and if it cotains the item `"b"` I want to return the whole element:

```
'b;abc\n'
```

how to do this with python? is it possible to do it with a `in` statement?

Comment: So many list comprehension questions recently. Four in a row. Does this seem odd to anyone else?

Comment: Level of list comprehension questions is too damn high.

Comment: I swear I've seen this question before but maybe I'm imagining it

Comment: @Haidro yes it's weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return you a list of all items that match your criteria, I assumed it may have more than one result matching, if there is only 1 result, the result list will have 1 item.

```
>>> input = ['a;1,2,3\n', 'b;abc\n']
>>> filter(lambda item:item.find('b;') == 0 ,input)
['b;abc\n']
```

Comment: This will check the entire list even when it finds the item

Comment: @jamylak I agree, but I made the assumption that instead of finding first occurence, the OP might be looking for all occurences of an item.

Comment: ah ok that's possible as well

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> L = ['a;1,2,3\n', 'b;abc\n']
>>> next((x for x in L if x.partition(';')[0] == 'b'), 'No match')
'b;abc\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function to extract a list of all matching elements from your structure:

```
def query(data, key):
    return [ x for x in data if x.startswith(key + ';') ]
```

Example use:

```
data = [
    'a;1,2,3\n',
    'b;abc\n',
    'c;4,5,6\n'
]
print query(data, 'b')
```

This gives the list `['b;abc\n']`.  If you ask for a key which isn't present, the result is the empty list.

Answer (score 0):

The other ways are most likely faster.

```
>>> L = ['a;1,2,3\n', 'b;abc\n']
>>> temp = [i.split(';') for i in L]
>>> ';'.join([x for x in temp if x[0] == 'b'][0])
'b;abc\n'
```